# How can i Override 302 Status in Http?

Tags: java, http, rest, servlets

client calling one rest service and its response  redirecting to another rest service using 
 sendRedirect() method

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/com.youtube.rest/api/v1/status/toreply"); .
```

from the second service result back to client.but when redirecting response from service 1 to service 2 , service 1 acknowledge back to client with its status 302. i don't want to return back any acknowledgement from service 1 to client. how can i avoid that acknowledgement ? or i want to return back status 200 acknowledgement .please suggest some way to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Sending back status code `302` is exactly what you told the server to do! That's what redirect does: It tells the client that it should lookup the resource under a different URL!

The status code for redirect is `302` (Found). Since HTTP 1.1 `303` (See other) or `307` (Moved temporarily) can be used too, but the servlet specification explicitely says that `302` must be used. See also [JavaDoc of `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29):

> (...) Calling this method sets the status code to SC_FOUND 302 (Found). (...)

**Forward to a resource in the same web-application**

If you instead want to forward the request to another resource/servlet in the same web application, use a `RequestDispatcher`:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    request.getRequestDispatcher("path-to-local-content");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**Forward to a resource in another web-application on the same server**

If the content is on the same server but in another web application, the `RequestDispatcher` must be created via `ServletContext`:

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    context.getRequestDispatcher("/<other-webapp>/<path-to-content>");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Note that some server do not allow cross-context dispatching and return a `null` dispatcher. On Tomcat, cross-context dispatching is disabled by default but can be enabled in the [`Context` configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

**Include content from 'foreign' web-servers**

If the content is not hosted locally on the same server (more precise: by the same servlet engine), you must open an `HttpURLConnection` to the foreign web server and retrieve the data by yourself.

See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests))
- [Reading InputStream from URL and write it by Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149058/reading-inputstream-from-url-and-write-it-by-servlet)

Comment: Hi..i agreed with you.if i want to use RequestDispatcher two service should be in same server.its working fine in servlet.but when i used in rest service its giving error.in my scenario client will call only one time. client shouldn't know what happening next and it will wait for only result.so how can i achieve this scenario ?

Comment: Is your second service "in the same server"? If yes, is it also within the same web application? What error do you get?

Comment: i'm using rest service hosted in tomcat.its not going to service2.its giving null error in RequestDispatcher  object.

Comment: @nixen09 i've extended my answer to address cross-context-dispatching.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41875/discussion-between-nixen09-and-isnot2bad)